# Atom searching in wrong directory for c++ file for compilation, does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: c++, windows, atom-editor

I have just downloaded and tested the MinGW's c++ compiler. In the terminal it works fine. Then I went to atom, downloaded gpp-compiler and tried compiling the same document I had compiled in the terminal. On atom however, I got this message:

```
g++: error: /mnt/c/Users/phfer/Desktop/cpp/new.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

As you can see, atom is searching for the file new.cpp in the directory /mnt/c/, instead of searching for it in C:\Users...
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I recommend to switch to a different IDE. Atom, VSCode and Sublime Text can be very good IDEs but it can be hard for beginners to configure them.

Comment: Try to change the default shell in Atom from powershell to command prompt.

Comment: Gonna try the shell thing and then maybe switch to a different IDE. Thanks!